# Rails: Mail::Message object isn't showing the message_id attribute but

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lazy-loading

I've a Mail::Message object that's created by the following way:

```
   mail_message_object = mailer.send(method_symbol, *parameters)
```

Here the method_symbol specifies it the type of the mail. Now, my problem is that when try to use this particular mail_message_object's message_id, it shows me a nil.

```
    mail_message_object.message_id --> nil
```

But if I do this :

```
    mail_message_object.to_s
```

or

```
    puts mail_message_object
```

and if I try to access the message_id, it shows me the right message_id.

```
    mail_message_object.message_id ---> 54f033bb1159a_1beec30f78570bd@samarth.mail
```

I don't understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be intended. You have to call `#encoded` (which `#to_s` does internally, too) to get a `message_id`:

> The MessageIdField object will automatically generate a unique message ID 
>   if you try and encode it or output it to_s without specifying a
>   message id.

https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/message.rb#L1426

This behaviour allows you to set a custom message ID. So if you need a generated ID the most simple approach is to call `mail_message_object.encoded` before, just as you did already.